# What language does BB-8 speak?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Does BB-8 in *Star Wars: The Force Awakens* speak some kind of binary (Morse-like) language? If so, how can people understand it (such as [Rey](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/45184/1799))?

Do we know the structure of it?

Comment: Similar question on SFF: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110907/does-bb-8-speak-the-same-language-as-r2-d2

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In-universe it's referred to as "***Binary***".

> The droid blurted out something harsh. Rey scoffed. **Her comfort with
>   all things mechanical had made her fluent in binary.** “Classified?
>   Really? Well, me too. Big secret. I’ll keep mine and you can keep
>   yours.” - <sub><sup>SW: The Force Awakens - Junior Novelisation</sup></sub>

and

> Q. Why is R2-D2 so hard to understand?
>
> A. **R2 speaks in binary**, a language of beeps and whistles. C-3PO
>   often has to translate to help everyone else understand what he's
>   saying. - <sub><sup>SW: Absolutely Everything You Need to
>   Know</sup></sub>

It's also referred to as "***Droidspeak***"

> BB-8 converses in 27th generation **droidspeak** code, a compressed
>   variant of the most common astromech language - <sub><sup>Star Wars:
>   The Force Awakens Visual Dictionary</sup></sub>

---

You may wish to note that this form of communication appears to be a dumbed-down version that can be understood by humans. When BB-8 attempts to communicate with R2-D2, his greeting is described as having a...

> ...transmission sequence too rapid and too exhaustive for any human to
>   follow.

Comment: Do they ever give a reason for this? The droids are clearly otherwise very sophisticated and some, like C-3PO, speak human languages as well as any current day smartphone. Yet, droids like BB-8 and R2D2 are so user unfriendly that you have to learn this astromech language just to communicate with them?

Comment: @Hack-R - The short answer is that R2 units are ship operations and repair droids. They aren't supposed to be interacting with humans apart from in those circumstances where you'd have a computer interface (like in an X-Wing) or where they'd have a counterpart (like on a starliner).

Comment: That makes sense. I appreciate the info.

Comment: @Hack-R - Asked and answered [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8220/why-cant-r2-d2-talk) if you're interested.

Answer (score 5):

From [starwars.wikia.com](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Binary)

> Binary or droidspeak was the language commonly spoken by droids. It consisted of a set of beeps and whistles strung together into what resembled sentences.
>
> The astromech BB-8 spoke in 27th generation droidspeak, a compressed
> variant of standard droidspeak.

Rey and few other also can understand them surely by learning. It must be like learning any other language.

Answer (score 2):

In-universe they call it Binary, which one could perhaps compare to morse code. You can learn morse code. It's not so much a language unto itself, but a way to encode language.

Of course, in reality, the noises the droids make are clearly analog and not binary at all, so it's actually more like a natural language in the aspect. (Though, as far as I know, there is no actual language created for the film like, for instance, they did with Klingon for Star Trek).

Answer (score 2):

Official DVD/Bluray Subtitles/CC simply call this ***Droid Language*** when it doesn't describe it as ***Beeps*** or ***Whistles***. This is used consistently throughout Episode 1-3. Episode 4-6 does not contain much non-verbal droid communication aside from R2. Pictured, a Vulture Droid at the start of Episode 3: Revenge of the Sith.

[image]

The same Subtitles use the language name for any other language, including Huttese and Galactic Basic (or Just "Basic", aka English or whatever language the movie was dubbed into). So ***officially, it's Droid or Droid Language***. *Of course this will be confirmed on the Force Awakens home release.*